# FB.ui feed or share not returning post_id response

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share, fb.ui

I am trying to use FB.ui share or feed on my test web site and want to get post_id on response message. App has permissions from my test user (user_posts, public_profile) and also i am checking if login status is "connected".

this is javascript code that i am trying to check login and let user to share link. `shareOnFacebook()` is triggered by a simple html button;

```
<script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: '****************',
            cookie: true,                     
            xfbml: true,                    
            version: 'v5.0'         
        });
    };
    function shareOnFacebook() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response1) {
            console.log(response1)
            if (response1.status === 'connected') {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    link: 'http://www.linktoshare.com',
                    picture: 'http://www.linktoshare.com/images/imagethumbnail.png'
                }, function (responseEnd) {
                    if (responseEnd) {
                        console.log(responseEnd); 
                        alert('Success');

                    } else {
                        alert('Fail');
                    }
                });     
            }
            else {
                FB.login(function (response2) {
                    console.log(response2)
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'feed',
                        link: 'http://www.linktoshare.com',
                        picture: 'http://www.linktoshare.com/images/imagethumbnail.png'
                    }, function (responseEnd) {
                        if (responseEnd) {
                            console.log(responseEnd);
                            alert('Success');

                        } else {
                            alert('Fail');
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

As you can see from below image, if i close pop-up, i can get response image like that;

[image: Popup Closed]

But when i share, reponse returns as an empty array like that;

[image: Success Post]

I know the error about "Https" is not important because my app is on development status.

What should i do to get post_id on response here?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should i do to get post_id on response here?

You **can’t** get the post ID any more, Facebook has removed that completely.

It was getting abused by shady developers and website owners to try and *force* users to share stuff, to get some kind of reward - which is absolutely not allowed. To stop that kind of spam, Facebook has removed this a while ago already.